# Bash: list different projections in directory of rasters .tiffs (gdalinfo)

Tags: bash, gdal

I acquired this BASH script which lists and tells me the different types of no data values in a directory.

```
basepath=/home/rose/Desktop/GreatExtentDSMnodatacleaned #change this as top level directory
nodata_NEW='-9999'

cd $basepath
dir_list=$(ls -d -1 $PWD/**) #create list of directories

for i in $dir_list
do
    cd $i    
        for f in *.tif; do
        gdalinfo "$f" | grep -o 'NoData Value\=[-0-9]*' || echo "NoData Value=None";
    done | uniq
    done
done
```

I want to find out if all the files inside a directory have the same projection, and list them if they do not. This is the gdalinfo of one of the .tif files I am working with, with the correct type of projection, datum and spheroid;

```
rose@Thinkpad:~/Desktop/GreatExtentDSM/1100LeeDam$ gdalinfo BQ26_2011_2000_2301.tif 
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: BQ26_2011_2000_2301.tif
Size is 960, 1440
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["NZGD2000 / New Zealand Transverse Mercator 2000",
    GEOGCS["NZGD2000",
        DATUM["New_Zealand_Geodetic_Datum_2000",
            SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.2572221008872,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6167"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4167"]],
PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
PARAMETER["central_meridian",173],
PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
PARAMETER["false_easting",1600000],
PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
UNIT["metre",1,
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
AUTHORITY["EPSG","2193"]]
Origin = (1612000.000000000000000,5410320.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (1.000000000000000,-1.000000000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( 1612000.000, 5410320.000) (173d 8'37.27"E, 41d27'31.02"S)
Lower Left  ( 1612000.000, 5408880.000) (173d 8'37.37"E, 41d28'17.72"S)
Upper Right ( 1612960.000, 5410320.000) (173d 9'18.65"E, 41d27'30.97"S)
Lower Right ( 1612960.000, 5408880.000) (173d 9'18.76"E, 41d28'17.67"S)
Center      ( 1612480.000, 5409600.000) (173d 8'58.01"E, 41d27'54.35"S)
Band 1 Block=960x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  NoData Value=-100
```

How do I modify the above script to check for varying projections etc?

Comment: Wouldn't `find . -name "*tif" -exec gdal_info {} \; |  grep "^AUTHORITY" | sort -u` be enough ?

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately, I tried `find . -name "*tif" -exec gdalinfo {} \; | grep "^AUTHORITY" | sort -u` it didn't give any outcome.

Comment: I tried `rose@Thinkpad:~/Desktop/test/0900Rich$ find . -name "*tif" -exec gdalinfo {} \; | grep "^AUTHORITY\=[****,****]*" || echo "^AUTHORITY=[None, None]" | uniq` It did return `^AUTHORITY=[None, None]` feel like I'm getting closer to the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer;

```
basepath=/home/rose/Desktop/test/0900Rich/*.tif
echo $basepath 
list=$(ls $basepath)

for i in $list
do
   gdalsrsinfo $i | grep 'PROJ.4 : '* || echo 'PROJ.4 : '
   #create text file with echo contents in it somewhere in here?
done
```

This BASH script gives a list of echo outputs;

```
PROJ.4 : '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=173 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs '
PROJ.4 : '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=173 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs '
PROJ.4 : '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=173 +k=0.9996 +x_0=1600000 +y_0=10000000 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs '
```

How do I create a text file with the output projections inside it? Tried defining the command in the for loop as a variable and >> to a text file but that did not work.

Comment: You can forward the output of the `for` loop to a file. Simply replace your `done` with `done > projections.txt` . This will create / overwrite the file.